# Laravel Blade Form::checkbox rendered as select

Tags: forms, checkbox, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I have a form that should display as checkboxes but is appearing as a select dropdown.

In the controller I defined the variables:

```
$user = Auth()->user();
$users  = User::all();
$assignedUsers = User::where('assigned', true)->get();
```

Here is where the form is defined in the view:

```
{{ Form::open( route('users.access', [$user->id]), ['type' => 'PUT']) }}
        
        {{ Form::checkbox(
            'Users', 
            [
                'label' => __('Select Users'), 
                'options' => $users,
                'value' => $assignedUsers
            ]
        ) }}

        {{ Form::button('submit', ['label' => __('Save changes')]) }}

    {{ Form::close() }}
```

The form is rendering but not as checkboxes but a select dropdown.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Form::checkbox() method accepts 3 arguments, `name`, `value`, and `default`. You seem passing wrong arguments for the checkbox list so it renders as dropdown, to make a checkbox list, you and use a loop, should be something like so:

```php
@foreach ($users as $user)

<label>
{{ Form::checkbox('users[]', $user->id, isset($assignedUsers[$user->id])) }} 
{{ $user->name }}
</label>

@endforeach
```

Note that I have converted your `$assignedUsers` variable to key by id for more convernience. You can use your own check method.

```php
$assignedUsers = User::where('assigned', true)->get()->keyBy('id');
```